# mysql workbench 6.2 CE : on windows 7 x64 ASCII

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

while launching mysql workbench an execution problem occurs:

> mysql workbench cannot be executed from a path that contains non-ASCII characters. this problem is imposed by used third party libraries. please run this application from the default installation path or at least  path which is all ASCII characters

i run it from the default installation path but it doesn't work

Comment: And what is your exact default installation path?

Comment: It is probably that you have installed it on `c:\Program Files (x86)` folder. Therefore the error. Try to install it somewhere else

Comment: i installed it on "D:/" already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless where you installed MySQL Workbench this path must not contain any non-ANSI characters atm (ANSI not ASCII, which is even more limited). Especially check out paths that include your user name (if you have non latin chars in the name). The reason is that a third-party lib (libzip) cannot handle utf-8 filenames on Windows (OSX and Linux are fine). Spaces in the path are ok.

This issue is already on our todo list and will be solved in a future version of MySQL Workbench.